# Android keyboard windowSoftInputMode issue inside Stacknavigator which is child of tabnavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In my react native app I have this in android menifest to avoid keyboard on TextInput.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

This is works in every use case except, on one screen which is inside `StackNavigator` which is again child of `TabNavigator`, this doesn't work.

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

I'm using

```
"react-navigation": "^1.5.9",
"react": "^16.1.0",
"react-native": "0.51.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

On the androidManisfest.xml set android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"

More in: https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility

Comment: I have done that. Issue is it is not working inside TabNavigator.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the KeyboardAvoidingView component described in this link:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.51/keyboardavoidingview

If you are programming for Android it is necessary to delete the line 
`android:windowSoftInputMode = "stateVisible"` of androidManifest.xml

Good luck!

Comment: No keyboard avoid doesn't work. I have tried all those options. Issue is TabNavigator.